# HTML select statement and button not working with PayPal

Tags: javascript, html

I am struggling to create a button for my website uses paypal subscriptions to manage users on the site. There are several different subscription options and I want to include them in a dropdown box instead of having seperate buttons for each option. However so far I can't figure it out. Currently the site is working using basically a default paypal button that uses a little javascript to make sure people accept the terms and conditions here is the current working code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" onsubmit="return confSubmit();"  method="post">
<p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><input name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" type="hidden" />    
<input name="hosted_button_id" value="HBP3ZG2KGRHC" type="hidden" /></span>
</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><input src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" name="submit"   alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" border="0" type="image" />
<img alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" border="0" height="1" width="1" /></span>
</p>
</form>
```

with the function confsubmit() being used to make user accept the terms and conditions:

```
function confSubmit() {
if (!document.getElementById("one").checked) {
alert("Please read and accept the terms and conditions in order to sign up.");
return false;
}}
```

Now I want to add to this a select statment along the lines of:

```
<select name="sub_types">
<option value="A1">1 Month </option>
<option value="A2">3 Months </option>
<option value="A3">6 Months </option>
<option value="A4">1 Year </option>
</select>
```

Now it is my understanding that the important part of the code is the button id value "HBP3ZG2KGRHC" from above which is used by paypal to select the proper subscription type. I can add this select statement into the form no problem but I can't figure out how to pass the selected option's value through the button to paypal so that it selects the proper subscription type. I hope that makes sense. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to vary the `hosted_button_id` value that is posted to PayPal. I haven't tried this, but it sounds like this might work:

Replace the

```
<input name="hosted_button_id" value="HBP3ZG2KGRHC" type="hidden" />
```

with

```
<select name="hosted_button_id">
    <option value="HBP3ZG2KGRHC">1 Month</option>
    <option value="[different button id for 3 months]">3 Months</option>
    <option value="[different button id for 6 months]">6 Months</option>
    <option value="[different button id for 1 year]">1 Year</option>
</select>
```

assuming you have several `hosted_button_id`s set up for the various subscription types.

Comment: This works!! Thanks so much I had tried to do it by naming the form and calling the selected option but PayPal always rejected that I think because of the form name parameter but your way works! Thanks for the help.